# this.router is undefined in AngularJS 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

Here is my method that registers a user and redirects to the main page:

```
onSubmit(){
    this.userService.createUser(this.user).subscribe(function (response) {
            alert('Successfully registered');
            localStorage.setItem('token', response['token']);
            this.router.navigate(['Home']);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}
```

above it, I have this constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService){}
```

I added `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to the main component:

```
providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]
```

When I try to register a user, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use arrow functions in your code to be able to use the "contextual this" (which corresponds to your component instance):

```
onSubmit(){
  this.userService.createUser(this.user).subscribe((response) => { // <---
        alert('Successfully registered');
        localStorage.setItem('token', response['token']);
        this.router.navigate(['Home']);
    }, (err) => { // <---
        console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: You r great man solved my frustrating issue.I had same issue while using sweetAlert2.